# Anki app for Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone, anki

Is there a Windows Phone app compatible with [Anki](http://ankisrs.net/) and [AnkiDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ichi2.anki)?

Requirements:

- Ability to synchronize with the [Anki](http://ankisrs.net/) server
- Ability to review

Any price is OK.

Answer (score 3):

No, there is currently no such app. The only solution is to open your web browser and use Anki's web interface called [AnkiWeb](https://ankiweb.net/):

[image]

Beware, several Windows Phone apps with "anki" in their names are getting money from unsuspecting users but are actually not compatible with Anki. [Example](https://www.reddit.com/r/windowsphone/comments/30auds/just_bought_ankiapp/):

> I bought *AnkiApp* thinking it was anki's attempt at an app for windows phone... I think I've been duped into paying $5 for a broken ass app.

A few reviews for AnkiApp: "*This is a knockoff of the real thing.*" "*Not actual anki, can't import from the desktop version.*" "*It's not Anki.*"

There is also an app called [Anki FlashCards WP](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/apps/anki-flashcards-wp/9nblggh3g146) but it only embeds AnkiWeb *(plus probably some advertisements and spyware, see the creepy permissions the app asks for)* so better use AnkiWeb directly.

Windows 10 might be able to [run reworked Android apps](http://www.theverge.com/2015/4/29/8511439/microsoft-windows-10-android-ios-apps-bridges), so there is hope, but it has not been tested yet.